# What is the difference here in between these two python statements?

Tags: python-3.x, list, if-statement, operators

Can I know what is the difference here ?
Assume A is 2d array and B is an int

```
if(A[i][j] == 2):
   res += B == 0
```

and

```
if(B == 0 and A[i][j] == 2):
   res += 1
```

Comment: Logically? Nothing. But the second is much clearer, and slightly more efficient (you don't even check the array if B is zero).

Comment: Please add complete code when posting a question.

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference between them, both are doing the same thing, adding 1 to res.

The first statements - checks if A[i][j] == 2 and then add value of 'B == 0' which is a **bool** to res, as in Python **True is 1 and False is 0**, it adds 1 to res if it is True.

The second statement, adds one to res by doing res = res + 1.